# Integrating with respect to an MCMC Kernel

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, monte-carlo

I'm currently trying to evaluate an integral with respect to an MCMC kernel, and I wanted someone else to read what I `proved' to see if it's really correct.  It just doesn't feel right.

Suppose I have an MCMC Kernel $K(a'|a)$ with stationary distribution $p(a)$.  I want to take the expectation of a function $f(a)$ given a point $a'$ through the kernel like so,

$$
\int_{a} f(a) K(a|a')
$$

I use detailed balance,

$$
= \int_{a} f(a) \frac{K(a'|a) p(a)}{p(a')}
$$
$$
= \mathbb{E}[f(a)K(a'|a)] \frac{1}{p(a')}
$$

Independence (at least I think they should be independent?)
$$
= \mathbb{E}[f(a)] \mathbb{E}[K(a'|a)] \frac{1}{p(a')}
$$

And detailed balance once again

$$
= \mathbb{E}[f(a)] p(a') \frac{1}{p(a')}
$$

Now this just seems incorrect.  If I interpret this correctly, it's telling me that if I take a large number of samples from $K(a|a')$ from any starting point $a'$ and integrate a function wrt to it, I might as well have had the original distribution.  I must have done something wrong.

Comment: Your use of independence is flawed, you can not replace $\mathbb{E}[f(a)K(a'|a)]$ with $\mathbb{E}[f(a)] \mathbb{E}[K(a'|a)]$. Indeed, you are claiming that $g(a)$ and $h(a)$ are independent, for some functions $f$ and $g$...